# How to get the distinct values in PieCloudDB Database？

Tags: sql, distinct

I have a table in my PieCloudDB database that has two columns:"vegetable" and "fruit". There are some redundant data. How can I get the distinct data and merge them in one column?

| Vegetable | Fruit |
| --- | --- |
| carrot | cherry |
| carrot | apple |
| cabbage | peach |
| mushroom | cherry |
| pepper | orange |
| pepper | strawberry |

| Distinct_Column |
| --- |
| peach |
| carrot |
| cabbage |
| pepper |
| mushroom |
| strawberry |
| cheery |
| orange |
| apple |

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this will give the results you want：

```
SELECT distinct_column FROM
(
  SELECT fruit AS distinct_column FROM PieCloudDB
  UNION
  SELECT vegetable AS distinct_column FROM PieCloudDB
) AS distinct_values;
```

Comment: No need for SELECT DISTINCT or subquery here, the UNION has already eliminated the duplicates.